# Calling a method in a method

Tags: java

I have to implement a method (Factory-method) called `createFromCelsius`, where i can create new Objects with the specific Temperature unit (celsius, kelvin...). I also created methods to convert the code from one unit to another. The problem is i dont know how i can connect the covert-methods to the `createFromCelsius` method. I tried to make all my methods and variables `abstact` so that i can call them. The Question: How can i implement the convert-methods in the create-methods?

Here's my code:

```java
public class Temperatur {

    private final float temp;

    /**
     * Static variable for kelvin
     */
    public static final float KELVIN_OFFSET = 273.15f;

    private Temperatur(float temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

      private static Temperatur createfromCelsius(final float temp) {
          return createfromCelsius(temp);
      }
  
      private static Temperatur createfromFahrenheit(final float temp) {
          return createfromFahrenheit(temp);
      }

      private static Temperatur createfromKelvin(final float temp) {
        return createfromKelvin(temp);
    }

    /**
     * converts celsius into kelvin
     *
     * @return
     */
    public float celsiusToKelvin() {
        return (temp + KELVIN_OFFSET);
    }

    /**
     * converts celsius into fahrenheit
     *
     * @return
     */
    public float celsiusToFahrenheit() {
        return (temp * (9f / 5f) + 32f);
    }

    /**
     * converts kelvin into celsius
     *
     * @return
     */
    public float kelvinToCelsius() {
        return (temp - KELVIN_OFFSET);
    }

    /**
     * converts kelvin into fahrenheit
     *
     * @return
     */
    public float kelvinToFahrenheit() {
        return (((temp - KELVIN_OFFSET) * (9f / 5f)) + 32f);
    }

    /**
     * converts fahrenheit into celsius
     *
     * @return
     */
    public float fahrenheitToCelsius() {
        return (((temp - 32f) * (5f / 9f)));
    }

    /**
     * converts fahrenheit into kelvin
     *
     * @return
     */
    public float fahrenheitToKelvin() {
        return ((temp + 459.67f) * (5f / 9f));
    } 
}
```

Comment: "*I tried to make all my methods and variables `abstact` so that i can call them.*" - That is not what `abstract` is used for. I recommend a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one by oracle (external link)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). --- The code - as is - has at least one endless-recursion in it. --- You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, `abstract` doesn't do what you want

A factory would work like this

```
private static Temperatur createfromCelsius(final float temp) {
    return new Temperatur(temp);
}
```

However, you should define what base unit of measurement your temp field in the class should be rather than passing through the factory parameter. For example, if you want to convert everything to Kelvin, that'd look like

```
private static Temperatur createfromCelsius(final float temp) {
    Temperatur t = new Temperatur(temp);  // or do the math directly here 
    t.temp = t.celsiusToKelvin();
    return t;
}
```

Then you'd only need public getter methods for one way conversions from Kelvin

Comment: "*And rather than define multiple mappings, you should define what unit of measurement your temp field in the class should be.*" - That is at least debatable. I would suggest to always store the temperature in Kelvin, and get the other temperature values through either dedicated getters or actual transformers. This would have the added benefit that the class can be designed as immutable.

Comment: My point was that "create from X" with `return new Temp(X)` is inconsistent, so converting all inputs into the same base unit should be preferred